# JAXB give namespace to non root element

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, saml

Requirement is something like this

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="something1" >
    <saml:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml="something2">
         <EncryptedData xmlns="something3" >
             some more tags with namespace
         </EncryptedData> 
    </saml:EncryptedAssertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

I have got prefix and namespace of root level using package-info.java but im unable to get namespace definition in non-root level i.e.

This is what I'm able to achieved

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="something1" xmlns:saml="something2" xmlns:ns6="someting3">
    <saml:EncryptedAssertion >
        <EncryptedData >
            some more tags with namespace
        </EncryptedData>
    </saml:EncryptedAssertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

package-info.java

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace="something1",

    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED,
    attributeFormDefault =XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED,
    xmlns={ 
            @XmlNs(prefix = "samlp", namespaceURI = "somthing1"),
            @XmlNs(prefix = "saml", namespaceURI = "something2"),
            @XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "something3"),
    }
)
```

I know namespace can be defined in parent/root node and it will be valid but I'm consuming web service so I'm not sure if name space declared in parent level will make any difference while unmarshal that is why I'm trying to generate exact saml response.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution?

Comment: @ronnyfm I have added the ans which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.
Not sure weather its right or wrong, but it worked for the scenario which i mentioned in question.

1. Added required attribute in particular JAXBclass

   ```
   public class EncryptedAssertionType {
   @XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns:saml")
   protected String samlNamespace;
   ```
2. Generated getters/setters for same variable and set the variable while marshalling

   ```
   EncryptedAssertionType encryptedAssertion = new EncryptedAssertionType();
   encryptedAssertion.setSamlNamespace("something2");
   ```

   You can add such attribute to all levels if you need

No need to include package-info.java

This gave me expected response

```
    <samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="something1" >
    <saml:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml="something2">
```